# Sourceforge org property for Ivy and Nexus

Tags: java, maven-2, ivy, nexus

When trying to use the following settings:

```
<dependency org="net.sourceforge.artifact" name="artifact" rev="2.0"/>
```

and:

```
<artifact pattern="http://localhost/nexus/content/repositories/releases/[module]/[artifact]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
```

Nexus expects

```
http:// ... net/sourceforge/artifact/artifact/revision/artifact.ext
```

but net and sourceforge are being completely dropped like so:

```
http:// ... artifact/artifact/revision/artifact.ext
```

Comment: I've added the answer below. In the above example Ivy drops off net and sourceforge in the URL because the wrong resolver is used.

Answer (score 0):

The correct resolver to use in this case is the IBiblio resolver found [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html). It will properly translate the periods in the org name to the proper url.